# Asp .Net Dropdownlist Vazio Após o Submit do Formulário

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownlist

Possuo um `dropdownlist` que é preenchido dinamicamente após dois `textboxes` terem sido preenchidos.
Quando faço o submit do formulário o `dropdownlist` está vazio, mesmo sendo preenchido dinamicamente.

**DropDownList**

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListReason" runat="server" CssClass="span8">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Selecione o motivo da solicitação" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

**Render**

```
     protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
     {
         //busca lista de dados
         foreach (var item in listaDeDados)
         {  
             Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(this.DropDownListReason.UniqueID, item.Id.ToString());
         }

         base.Render(writer);
     }
```

**Jquery**

```
//faz o get dos dados
   $.each(response, function (key, value) {
      if (value.requiresDescription) {
         requiresDescription.push(value.id);
      }

      $("#<%= DropDownListReason.ClientID %>").append($("<option />").val(value.id).text(value.description));
   });
```

*O submit do formulário é um evento on click de um botão.*

Como faço para que ao preencher dinamicamente os dados, eles persistam no submit do formulário ?

Comment: O que você quer dizer em persistir no submit? Manter o valor após o recarregamento da página?

Comment: O formulário é postado ao clicar em um botão que dispara um evento on click, nesse evento o dropdownlist já está vazio, ele deveria estar preenchido para ser validado e ir para uma nova página.

Comment: Acredito que se você está populando seu dropdown no client, esse controle precisa estar dentro de uma tag <form> e você só recuperará esse valor no servidor através de um Request

Comment: Isso eu preencho no lado do cliente, a tag do dropdownlist está sim dentro da tag <form>, Como efetuar esse último passo que falou ?

Comment: Adiciona o método onde você está recuperando as informações do formulário após o submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que ocorre é que seu novo item não está no `viewstate` do controle, portanto quando o .net "remonta" sua página ele perde o valor.

Uma boa opção seria você guardar este valor por exemplo em um `hidden field` e inseri-lo no dropdown no `Page_Init`, uma vez que o `viewstate` somente será carregado no `Page_Load`.

Comment: Não foi exatamente o que eu fiz para resolver, mas me deu uma excelente ideia.

Comment: Maravilha, se puder, compartilhe sua ideia para ajudar quem estiver com o mesmo problema e chegar a este tópico.
De qualquer forma, alterações no conteúdo por javascript e viewstate não conversam muito bem... na grande maioria das vezes é necessário armazenar os dados em um hiddenfield para depois manipular o valor no code behind.